# wordpress : exclude advertising from some posts by array ids

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, posts

We have this array

```
$exarray = Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 200 )
```

We used implode to get values only as this

```
$excludePosts1 = implode(",", $exarray);
```

that print excluded posts ids  100,200

but when we use this code

```
if(!is_single(array(100,200))) >> Worked
```

but when use $excludePosts1 variable like this

```
if(!is_single(array($excludePosts1))) >> Not working although same values !!
```

Where is the error ?

Comment: Correct your `$exarray`.

Answer (score 0):

First set your array just like this:

```
<?php
$exarray = array(
    "0" => "100",
    "1" => "200",
);

print_r($exarray[0]);
?>
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/645719)

Then you can do like this:

```
is_single($exarray[0]);
is_single($exarray[1]);
```

Comment: this mean we must write code with **many times** to check if post id in this array if(!is_single(array($exarray[0])))  ...  if(!is_single(array($exarray[1]))).... and so on !!!

Comment: am just give you an example you can use loop to solved this .. !!

Answer (score 0):

In above case, you got a problem in [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) declaration.

Below are some example how can you declare array and rest of the things are looking correct. If you can any problem please comment down below.

**Example #1**

```
$exarray = Array ( 100, 200 );
```

**Example #2**

```
$exarray = array(
    "0" => "100",
    "1" => "200",
);
```